# Looking for patterns in binary files

Tags: c, linux, hex, bin

I'm working on a small project in C where I have to parse a binary file of undocumented file format. As I'm quite new to C I have two questions to some more experienced programmers.

The first seems to be an easy one. How do I extract all the strings from the binary file and put them into an array? Basically I am looking for a simple implementation of *strings* program in C.

When I open the binary file in any text editor I get a lot of rubbish with some readable strings mixed in. I can extract this strings using *strings* in the command line. Now I'd like to do something similar in C, like in the pseudocode below:

```
while (!EOF) {
     if (string found) {
          put it into array[i]
          i++
       }
     return i;
}
```

The second problem is a little bit more complicated and is, I believe, the proper way of achieving the same thing. When I look at the file in HEX editor it's easy to notice some patterns. For example before each string there is a byte of value 02 (0x02) followed by the length of the string and the string itself. For example 02 18 **52 4F 4F 54 4B 69 57 69 4B 61 4B 69** is a string with the string part in bold.

Now the function I'm trying to create would work like this:

```
while(!EOF) {
     for(i=0; i<buffer_size; ++i) {
          if(buffer[i] hex value == 02) {
               int n = read the next byte;
               string = read the next n bytes as char;
               put string into array;
          }
     }
}
```

Thanks for any pointers. :)

Comment: TLV - Type, Length, Value - encoding is common.  Your example is not conclusive; the length 0x18 should be followed by a 24-byte string, yet you show only 12 bytes...is it counting nybbles instead of bytes?

Comment: Yes, it seems like it counts single hex digits, so the string length in bytes would be n/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first seems to be an easy one. How do I extract all the strings from the binary file and put them into an array?

Figure out what character range represents printable ASCII characters. Iterate across the file, checking if characters are ASCII characters, and counting up for adjacent ASCII characters. By default, `strings` will treat sequences of four or more characters as strings; when you find the next non-ASCII character, check if the number has been exceeded; if it has, output the string. Some book-keeping is necessary.

> The second problem is a little bit more complicated and is, I believe, the proper way of achieving the same thing.

Your pseudocode is essentially correct. You can manually compare the contents of `buffer[i]` with an integer (e.g. 2). Reading a byte is as simple as incrementing `i`. Make sure you don't overrun the buffer, and make sure the array your reading the string to is big enough (if the size parameter is only one byte, you can get away with a 255 length array buffer.)

Comment: +1. You need to create a isStringChar() function that takes a character and returns true if it is in a string (e.g. if its a-z). And you need to keep a string that is the current running string of the characters you have seen so far. Add a loop to parse characters one at a time and you are done.

Comment: Ok, that seems helpful. I'll try to implement the first method. Looking at the files a bit more it seems that 02 doesn't always signify a string though and there are places where 02 is followed by unreadable characters.

Comment: If you're reverse engineering the data format, the first thing you should do is do some hand inspection with a hex editor / strings / other generic types of tools. When you have a theory for the format, then start coding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your solution will work: what if you find a string with 350 char length? 
Numbers can be part of a string or you can consider them "rubbish"?

I think the most safe way is

1. Define what you consider string and what you consider "rubbish" - for instance ":,!?" are "string" or "rubbish"?
2. Define a minimum string length to be considered a "readable" string
3. Parse the file looking for every group of char with length >= minimum.
   I know, it's boring, but I think it's the only safe way. Good luck!

Comment: If you said 250 instead of 350...a single byte (assuming 8-bit bytes, as normal) only holds values up to 255, of course.